# All characters not displaying in the text field of a crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, textfield

I have a field in crystal reports which concatenates three strings, each of 35 characters in the database. For example : aaaaaaabbbbbbbssssssswwwwwwwqqqqqqq, aaaaaaabbbbbbbssssssswwwwwwwqqqqqqq, aaaaaaabbbbbbbssssssswwwwwwwqqqqqqq
But when I preview the report, only 14 characters are displayed, i.e. aaaaaaabbbbbbbssss, aaaaaaabbbbbbbssss, aaaaaaabbbbbbbssss

Checked the length of these columns in the Database, its 35.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Click on field - Format Object

Tick the "Can Grow" Option